# Sling Dynamic Include in AEM

Tags: caching, aem, sdi

I am trying the same implementation as in http://www.cognifide.com/our-blogs/cq/sling-dynamic-include/

After the SDI OSGi configuration and dispatcher configs are done, the include tag --#include virtual="/path/to/resource" is requested with nocache.html selector, but the actual content is not getting displayed and the header section is removed from the page.

Any pointers what could be wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide some more details what the steps you have done.?

Comment: I managed to get this working by adding Options +Includes in the web server config which is not mentioned in SDI documentation in github. Not sure if this is related to the version I am using. Versions- aem 6.1, apache server 2.2.15, dispatcher 4.2.0.

Comment: (1) In httpd.conf, added the below as i did not use vhost in local.
    <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName 127.0.0.1
  DocumentRoot D:/java/apachehttpserver/htdocs <Directory "D:/java/apachehttpserver/htdocs">
  AddType text/html .html
  AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .html
  Options +Includes
 </Directory>
  <Directory "D:/java/apachehttpserver/htdocs">
    <IfModule disp_apache2.c>
      SetHandler dispatcher-handler
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride None
 SetOutputFilter INCLUDES
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>    

(2) cq included the header component in the boilerplate template

Comment: is everything working for you with the SDI right now ?

Comment: yes, it is working fine.

Comment: Video that helps in configuring SDI - 
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/platform-repository/using/sling-dynamic-include-technical-video-setup.html